# laravel airlock issue with creating tokens: 'tokenable_id' cannot be null

Tags: laravel, laravel-airlock

Have upgraded to Laravel 7 and have installed Laravel/Airlock.

Having followed the installation instructions if try to create a token i get an error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tokenable_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `personal_access_tokens` (`name`, `token`, `abilities`, `tokenable_id`, `tokenable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (api-token, 31afd4da089878bd2cd562264bd2d8c789c7a1f91e47f6c3969bce2fc19a7329, ["order:create","order:view","WLR3:check_availability"], ?, App\Models\User, 2020-03-06 10:44:05, 2020-03-06 10:44:05))

in my TokenController.php i have:

```php
public function create(User $user, Request $request)
{
    $token_name = $request->input('token_name', 'api-token');

    $abilities = $request->input('abilities', [
        'order:create',
        'order:view',
        'WLR3:check_availability'
    ]);

    $token = $user->createToken($token_name, $abilities);

    return $this->view($user, $request);
}
```

What have i missed that could be causing this error?

On the User Model it starts with:

```php
use Laravel\Airlock\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable /* implements MustVerifyEmail */
{
    use HasRoles, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $guard_name = 'web';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rookie mistake...  It seems that the $user created on the dependency injection was not a valid one.

I need to add:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

to the create method, so it now reads as:

```php
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $token_name = $request->input('token_name', 'api-token');

        $abilities = $request->input('abilities', [
            'order:create',
            'order:view',
            'WLR3:check_availability'
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken($token_name, $abilities);

        return $this->view($user, $request);
    }
```

this now works!